# WSO2 Modify running processes

Tags: business-process-management, wso2

Is there a way to alter processes/components in WSO2 at runtime (in-flight)?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean hot update of artifacts or updating WSO2 components?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to altering java processes on fly. Unfortunately there is no such a way to achieve this.

If you can post ypur exact use case we might able to provide you a more fair feed back.

Thank You,
Dharshana.